# Building basic calculator in JavaScript - works first time but on loop I get "___ is not a function" error

Tags: javascript, function, for-loop

So I've just tried to build a basic calculator in JavaScript that can use standard operators. I've built a number of functions to do the basic calculation, and then one to loop back to do another calculation if the user wishes to, as per below code (can provide the whole file if necessary).

I've looked at other calculator questions and haven't found a solution. I've also looked at a sample solution for this that works fine, but the sample solution automatically loops at the end instead of having a conditional depending on whether the user wants to or not i.e. it doesn't use the loopCalc function.

```
//prompt to return a string
function stringInput (prompt) {
    console.log('\n' + prompt);
    return readline.prompt();
}

//ask for an operator
function op() {
    return stringInput('Please enter an operator');
}

//do the calculation
function calculator() {
    op = op();
    num = numArray(op);
    performOneCalc();
    console.log('\nThe answer is ' + answer + '.');
}

//loop when user says "yes" to another calc
function loopCalc() {
    for (askAgain(); oneMore == ('yes'); askAgain()) {
        if (oneMore == 'yes') {
            calculator();
        }
        else if (oneMore == 'no') {
            break;
        }
        else { 
            console.log('I neeed a yes or no answer');
            askAgain();
        }
    }
}

calculator();
loopCalc();
```

When the calculator function is called, it runs through fine.

Then it calls the loopCalc function, which in turn calls the askAgain function which works fine, and if the user says "yes" then it tries to call the calculator function again but fails because of the op function.

I get this error:

```
op = op();
         ^
```

> TypeError: op is not a function

Any advice would be much appreciated!

Comment: `op = op()` will execute the function an  *replace it* with the output. So, the next time that line is executed `op()` will fail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues that are wrong with our code, may i suggest you use a [linting tool](https://mikecavaliere.com/javascript-linting-what-developers-need-to-know/) to help you discover errors or use [javascript string mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode). In strict mode, your code will not run.

Anyway, back to your problem: `op = op();`

There is your problem.

When you do `function op() { ... }` you create a function global variable.

and when you do `op = ...` you create another global variable, but the second global variable overwrites the first one with a value, so `op` is no longer a function, but later on you try to call it as a function.

```
//prompt to return a string
function stringInput (prompt) {
    console.log('\n' + prompt);
    return readline.prompt();
}

//ask for an operator
function op() {
    return stringInput('Please enter an operator');
}

//do the calculation
function calculator() {
    num = numArray(op());
    performOneCalc();
    console.log('\nThe answer is ' + answer + '.');
}

//loop when user says "yes" to another calc
function loopCalc() {
    for (askAgain(); oneMore == ('yes'); askAgain()) {
        if (oneMore == 'yes') {
            calculator();
        }
        else if (oneMore == 'no') {
            break;
        }
        else { 
            console.log('I neeed a yes or no answer');
            askAgain();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

replace the

```
op = op();
```

with something like:

```
operator = op();
```

or just rename the function

EDIT: Comment by @VLAZ explains the reason for it:
op = op() will execute the function an replace it with the output. So, the next time that line is executed op() will fail

Comment: Your answer could be improved by explaining what the `op = op();` is doing wrong. Yes, it's in a comment on the question, but those aren't meant to stick around forever.

Comment: You`re right I will update the answer and give credit to the comment that @VLAZ made

Comment: The more details you can give, the better your answer will be. Not just for OP, but for everyone else who may find this question later.